# Create column with nested list aggregation in Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe with this structure

```
val df = Seq(
  ("john", "tomato", 1),
  ("john", "carrot", 4),
  ("bill", "apple", 1),
  ("john", "tomato", 2),
  ("bill", "taco", 2)      
).toDF("name", "food", "price")
```

I need to make nested lists aggregating, like this

```
name | acc                       |
-----+---------------------------+
john |[(tomato, 3), (carrot, 4)] |
bill |[(apple, 1), (taco,2 )]    |
```

I tried this way, but it is not right.

```
 dff.groupBy($"name")
  .agg(collect_list(struct($"food", $"price")).as("foods"))
  .show(false)
```

```
+----+------------------------------------+
|name|set                                 |
+----+------------------------------------+
|john|[[tomato,1], [carrot,4], [tomato,2]]|
|bill|[[apple,1], [taco,2]]               |
+----+------------------------------------+
```

how can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need two `groupBy` and `aggregations` and use of `collect_list`, `struct` and `sum` *inbuilt functions*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy("name", "food").agg(sum("price").as("price"))
  .groupBy("name").agg(collect_list(struct("food", "price")).as("acc"))
```

You will have output `dataframe` as

```
+----+------------------------+
|name|acc                     |
+----+------------------------+
|john|[[carrot,4], [tomato,3]]|
|bill|[[taco,2], [apple,1]]   |
+----+------------------------+
```